# difference between two dates in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have these 2 dates stored in mysql :

```
2012-10-05
2012-10-10
```

I got the dates returned using php/mysql now I need to find out how many days separate them.
in this example it would be 5days.
any suggestion of what would be the best way to do it ?

Comment: [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) accepts a string and returns an a unix timestamp.  If you did `strtotime()` for each and subtracted, you'd have the difference between the two dates in seconds.  Divide appropriately and you're on your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(date1, date2)
FROM yourtable
```

as per the MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

datediff() returns the difference of `date1 - date2` in days.

Comment: thanks for this approach I didnt know you could do it through sql, only knew about php.

Comment: Better to do it in the database, rather than having to force mysql to convert its internal date format to a string, then force php to convert that string back to a php-native timestamp. pointless round-tripping should be avoided.

Comment: true. can I select more than those fields ? like SELECT DATEDIFF(date1, date2),users.email,users.id FROM mytable. I will be emailing the ones where date1-date2 is bigger than 5days

Comment: of course, using a function as a field in a query call doesn't prevet you from selecting any other fields/function calls you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = strtotime("2012-10-05");
$date2 = strtotime("2012-10-10");



$days = floor(abs($date2 - $date1)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d days",$days);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2012-10-05');
$date2 = new Datetime('2012-10-10');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->format('%R%d days');  // +5 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

$date1 = "2007-03-24";
$date2 = "2009-06-26";

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);